# How can I add a column of one file to other file with spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I add a column of one file to other file with spark RDD?

File1 input contains the below input:

```
Priority,qty,sales
Low,6,261.54
High,44,10123.02
High,27,244.57
High,30,4965.75
Null,22,394.27
```

File2 contains below input:

```
priority,grade
Low,A
High,B
Null,K
```

My required output should be like:

```
Priority,qty,sales,grade
Low,6,261.54,A
High,44,10123.02,B
High,27,244.57,B
High,30,4965.75,A
Null,22,394.27,K
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Normally, the code/data is usually pasted in the greyed box, so your initial template was more in line with the way questions are posted here on SO. Secondly, the Null is the Null/None value or it a string like `High/Low`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rdd Solution:** Here is the RDD solution to it. Use [`left outer join`](http://apachesparkbook.blogspot.com/2015/12/join-leftouterjoin-rightouterjoin.html).

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('Low',6,261.54),('High',44,10123.02),('High',27,244.57),
                      ('High',30,4965.75),('Null',22,394.27)]).map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1],x[2])))
rdd.collect()
    [('Low', (6, 261.54)),
     ('High', (44, 10123.02)),
     ('High', (27, 244.57)),
     ('High', (30, 4965.75)),
     ('Null', (22, 394.27))]

rdd1 = sc.parallelize([('Low','A'),('High','B'),('Null','K')])
rdd1.collect()
    [('Low', 'A'), ('High', 'B'), ('Null', 'K')]

rdd2=rdd.leftOuterJoin(rdd1).map(lambda x:(x[0],x[1][0][0],x[1][0][1],x[1][1]))
rdd2.collect()
    [('High', 27, 244.57, 'B'),
     ('High', 30, 4965.75, 'B'),
     ('High', 44, 10123.02, 'B'),
     ('Low', 6, 261.54, 'A'),
     ('Null', 22, 394.27, 'K')]
```

**DataFrame Solution:** You can use [`left join`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) to do this. I assume that `Null` is a `string` and not `None`.

```
# Creating the DataFrames
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Low',6,261.54),('High',44,10123.02),('High',27,244.57),
                                 ('High',30,4965.75),('Null',22,394.27)],
                                 ['Priority','qty','sales'])
df.show()
+--------+---+--------+
|Priority|qty|   sales|
+--------+---+--------+
|     Low|  6|  261.54|
|    High| 44|10123.02|
|    High| 27|  244.57|
|    High| 30| 4965.75|
|    Null| 22|  394.27|
+--------+---+--------+

df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Low','A'),('High','B'),('Null','K')],
                                 ['Priority','grade'])
df1.show()
+--------+-----+
|Priority|grade|
+--------+-----+
|     Low|    A|
|    High|    B|
|    Null|    K|
+--------+-----+
```

Applying `left` join.

```
df_joined = df.join(df1,['Priority'],how='left')
df_joined.show()
+--------+---+--------+-----+
|Priority|qty|   sales|grade|
+--------+---+--------+-----+
|    High| 44|10123.02|    B|
|    High| 27|  244.57|    B|
|    High| 30| 4965.75|    B|
|     Low|  6|  261.54|    A|
|    Null| 22|  394.27|    K|
+--------+---+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are just trying to join `file2` to `file1` using the `priority` column as key. In spark, you can use dataframes which are much more convenient for that kind of things than RDDs. It's just a few lines of code.

```py
file1 = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(".../file1")
file2 = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(".../file2")
output = file1.join(file2, ['priority'])
output.show()
+--------+---+--------+-----+
|Priority|qty|   sales|grade|
+--------+---+--------+-----+
|     Low|  6|  261.54|    A|
|    High| 44|10123.02|    B|
|    High| 27|  244.57|    B|
|    High| 30| 4965.75|    B|
|    Null| 22|  394.27|    K|
+--------+---+--------+-----+
```

And if you want to write it to the disk,

```py
output.write.option("header", "true").csv(".../output")
```